# Sending mail with Google Apps Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-applications

I'm trying to send an e-mail to the instructions: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/sending-mail-with-mail-api

But I get this error:

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CancelledException: The API call remote_socket.CreateSocket() was explicitly cancelled.
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall (ApiProxy.java:118)
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall (ApiProxy.java:67)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.apiProxyMakeSyncCall (SocketApiHelper.java:93)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.makeSyncCall (SocketApiHelper.java:58)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.AppEngineSocketImpl.createSocket (AppEngineSocketImpl.java:497)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.AppEngineSocketImpl.connectToAddress (AppEngineSocketImpl.java:362)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.AppEngineSocketImpl.connect (AppEngineSocketImpl.java:352)
at java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:612)
at java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:540)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket (SocketFetcher.java:321)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket (SocketFetcher.java:237)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer (SMTPTransport.java:1927)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect (SMTPTransport.java:654)
at javax.mail.Service.connect (Service.java:295)
at javax.mail.Service.connect (Service.java:176)
at javax.mail.Service.connect (Service.java:125)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0 (Transport.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send (Transport.java:124)
at ru.usyservice.model.mail.PopupMail.sendMail (PopupMail.java:88)
```

What could be the reason?

My method:

```
private void sendMail(String mail) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        try {
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("administrator@appname.appspot.com", "Mr.x"));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress("somepeople@gmail.com", "Mr.y"));
            msg.setSubject("Test mail");
            msg.setContent(mail, "text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
            Transport.send(msg);
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I ran into a similar but not identical problem about a year ago on Google App Engine. The solution was that I needed to create a separate queue/thread that would retry the mail if the send failed. Google App Engine has a service that does this for you and they provide sample code; it's not something that you can code yourself because multi-threaded code isn't really supported.

Also I recall there were some steps I needed to follow to set up mail send and to bump up the maximum number of sends my account was allowed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
But, i found a mistake in pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

I found a mistake in pom.xml, library javax.mail has been added, but google is using his lib, which is included in the appengine-api-1.0-sdk
I deleted javax.mail, add appengine-api-1.0-sdk in Maven, and it worked!